# Unable to compare the given input of lat and long with generated co-ordinates

Tags: python-3.x

In the below prg I'm able to generate lat and long of given max and min co-ordinates. But I'm unable to compare the given input of lat and long with generated co-ordinates and display whether the co-ordinates are inside or outside. It would be great help if someone rectifies the problem
The generated co-ordinates are in this order:

**Lat** 
12.941312
12.941313
12.941314
12.941315
12.941316
12.941317
12.941318
12.941319
12.94132
12.941321

**Long** 77.565712
77.565713
77.565714
77.565715
77.565716
77.565717
77.565718
77.565719
77.56572
77.565721

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(12.941312, 12.941389, 0.000001)
b=np.arange(77.565712, 77.565789, 0.000001)
Lat=float(input("ENter the lat:"))
Long=float(input("ENter the long:"))
for lat,long in zip(a,b):

    s=float("{:.6f}".format(lat))
    #print(s)

    t=float("{:.6f}".format(long))
    #print(t)
    if Lat==s and Long==t:
        print("Inside")
else:
    print("Outside")
```

Comment: Can you provide input samples that should work and others that shouldn't ?

Comment: If i give lat as 12.941312 and long as 77.565811. It should return inside. Both input of  Lat and Long should match with generated co-ordinates irrespective of order. Input lat and long should be present inside generated lat and lon

Comment: Your script only compares with (lat, long) with same index: (lat[0], long[0]), (lat[1], long[1]). Your problem is to check if given longitude is in `a` and if given latitude is in `b`. You should not loop over the `zip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must compare the coordinates independently:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12.941312, 12.941389, 0.000001)
a_float = [float("{:.6f}".format(lat)) for lat in a]
b = np.arange(77.565712, 77.565813, 0.000001)
b_float = [float("{:.6f}".format(long)) for long in b]
Lat = float(input("ENter the lat:"))
Long = float(input("ENter the long:"))
if Lat in a_float and Long in b_float:
    print("Inside")
else:
    print("Outside")
```